# One serial port in multiple forms

Tags: serial-port

I would like to ask you folks about passing one serial port to multiple forms in one project. I acomplished to passed it from "main" form to "Form1" but I don't know how to handle it by buttons, combobox, etc. I want to change serial port parameters in seperate form. I'm quite new in c# and i can't figure it out.

Form "main"

```
namespace RS232
{
public partial class mainform : Form
{
    Form1 frm1;
    Form2 frm2;

    public mainform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Mitasubaszi controller";
        frm1 = new Form1(sport);
        frm2 = new Form2();            
    }      

    public void toolStripMenuItem9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult resultquit;
        resultquit = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?","Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (resultquit == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (sport.IsOpen) sport.Close();
            Close();
        }           

    }

    private void toolStripMenuItem6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.ShowDialog();   
    }


    private void toolStripMenuItem5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
}
```

Form "Form1"

```
namespace RS232
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int brate;


    public Form1(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initvalue(main);                     
    }      


    public void initvalue(System.IO.Ports.SerialPort initport)
    {   
        boxbaud.SelectedIndex = 5;
        boxdata.SelectedIndex = 3;
        boxpar.SelectedIndex = 0;
        boxstop.SelectedIndex = 2;
        checkDTR.Checked = true;
        checkRTS.Checked = true;
        initport.BaudRate = 9600;
        initport.DataBits = 8;
        initport.PortName = "COM1";
        initport.DtrEnable = true;
        initport.RtsEnable = true;
        initport.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Even;
        initport.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.Two;           
    }    

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();            
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void DTR_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkDTR.Checked) .DtrEnable = true;
        else .DtrEnable = false;            
    }

    public void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (.IsOpen) .Close();
            int comvalue = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
            string comport = String.Format("COM{0}", comvalue);

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Port does not exist");
        }
    }

    public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (boxbaud.SelectedIndex == -1) MessageBox.Show("Baud Rate is not selected", "Warning");
        else
        {
            brate = Convert.ToInt32(boxbaud.SelectedItem);

        }

    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string stat;
        if (.IsOpen) stat = "Open";
        else stat = "Close";
        string br = Convert.ToString(.BaudRate);
        string dts = Convert.ToString(.DtrEnable);
        string com = Convert.ToString(.PortName);
        string par = Convert.ToString(.Parity);
        string dat = Convert.ToString(.DataBits);
        string rts = Convert.ToString(.RtsEnable);
        string stop = Convert.ToString(.StopBits);
        string text = string.Format("Status: {0}\nPort: {1}\nBaud rate: {2}\nData bits: {3}\nParity: {4}\nStop bits: {5}\nDTS: {6}\nRTS {7}", stat, com, br, dat, par, stop, dts, rts);
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }

    private void checkRTS_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkRTS.Checked) .RtsEnable = true;
        else .RtsEnable = false;
    }

    private void boxpar_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (boxpar.SelectedItem == "Even") .Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Even;
        if (boxpar.SelectedItem == "Mark") .Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Mark;
        if (boxpar.SelectedItem == "None") .Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
        if (boxpar.SelectedItem == "Odd") .Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Odd;
        if (boxpar.SelectedItem == "Space") .Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Space;
    }

    private void boxdata_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (boxdata.SelectedIndex == -1) MessageBox.Show("Data bits are not selected", "Warning");
        else
        {
            int bdata = Convert.ToInt32(boxdata.SelectedItem);
            .DataBits = bdata;
        }
    }

    private void boxstop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (boxstop.SelectedItem == "1") .StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
        if (boxstop.SelectedItem == "1.5") .StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.OnePointFive;
        if (boxstop.SelectedItem == "2") .StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.Two;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!.IsOpen) .Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid port parameters");
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (.IsOpen) .Close(); 
    }  


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a single `SerialPort` in your whole application, You can  create an `static` class with a static Property of type `SerialPort`.

```
public static class SerialPortCommunicator
{
   private static SerialPort _serialPort=new SerialPort();

   public static SerialPort SerialPort
    {
        get { return _serialPort; }
        set { _serialPort = value; }
    }
}
```

Now you can change the value of its properties from everywhere inside your project.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_InForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            // Manipulate every other properties here (inside this from)
        }
    }



public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_InFrom2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.BaudRate = 4900;
        // Manipulate every other properties here(inside this form as well)
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting NullReferenceException when program is starting or TypeInitializationException when I changed class like this: `public static class portclass
    {
        public static Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        public static Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        public static SerialPort sport { get; set; }
    }
}`

Comment: Mate. There are 3 different classes. Look twice to my listing. It is not like the thing you have written at all. You just need to define a static class and define a property of `SerialPort`. Then you can open your form, double click on a button you had put on your form. and write for example `SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.BaudRate = 4900` inside the its click method. Let me know if you could resolve it.

Comment: Sorry, when I was writing last comment it looks less pretentiously. I have problem because I can't even change value using your way. When I'm writing for e.g. SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.BaudRate = 4900 I'm getting NullReferenceException. I can't change any parameter of serial port, because this exception is appearing.

Comment: Ok, I figure it out. I forgot to add in form1 `portclass.sport = new SerialPort(); `. Thanks for everything and once again sorry for the first comment :)